# while inserting i can insert danish character in proper format in sqlite Db but while retrieving my query returns no result

Tags: sqlite

while inserting i can insert danish character in proper format in sqlite Db but while retrieving my query returns no result

```
String searchQuery= "SELECT  * FROM  article,product  where article.ItemNo=product.ItemNo ";


        if(searchText.length()>0)
        {
            searchQuery += " AND (article.itemNo like '"+ searchText +"%' OR product.Description like '"+ searchText +"%')";
        }
```

in debug mode query is

```
`SELECT  * FROM  article,product  where article.ItemNo=product.ItemNo  AND (article.itemNo like '%ø%' OR product.Description like '%ø%')..`
```

No result returns
Proper query will be

```
SELECT  * FROM  article,product  where article.ItemNo=product.ItemNo  AND (article.itemNo like '%Ø%' OR product.Description like '%Ø%');
```

the desired description field value in Db is MØNTPUNG.

I am wondering is there any issue of case sensitivty?I am using UTF8 encoding for my raw file that will insert data to DB.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) says:

> SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.

To handle non-ASCII characters correctly, store an uppercase version of your string(s) in a separate column, and search in that with an uppercase search pattern.

Comment: String searchQuery= "SELECT  * FROM  article,product  where article.ItemNo=product.ItemNo ";
  
  
  if(searchText.length()>0)
  {
   //TODO search was not working for danish lowercase letters...so we are converting them to uppercase ans doing search.
   searchQuery += " AND (article.itemNo like '"+ searchText +"%' OR product.Description like '"+ searchText.toUpperCase() +"%')";}   ..this solved my problem by converting to Uppercase